# Invalid Syntax for except ValueError

Tags: python

I keep getting this invalid syntax error here: except ValueError: It's giving me a carat after 'except'. I am wondering if I need to line up the 'excepts' but I tried that and I still got the same syntax error. What's wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
from subprocess import *
import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, solution_id, input_file = argv

#creating time stamp and returning as a string to add to solution id log name
def timeIzNow():  
    full = time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return full

#set up logging to file
LOG_FILENAME = solution_id  + timeIzNow() 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s %(process)d',
                    datefmt='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 
                    filename=LOG_FILENAME,
              filemode='w')   
# defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# setting a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# telling the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# adding the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

#set up configuration Parser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/objectItems.cfg')
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/action.cfg')

#get objects
objects = config.get('Objects', 'objects')

#get actions
actions = config.get('Actions', 'actions')

#if no object is found, run error
assert(sys.argv[1] != None), "object does not exist"

#logging debug 
#logging.debug('object does not exist')

#Get inputs and check value and path to file


try:
    f = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb")) 
except FileNotFoundError:
    logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')   
    for line in f:
        #process (line) 

        for row in f:     
            if solution_id != row[2]:
                except ValueError: 
                    logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
            else:
                print row





finally: 
     print "all error checks done!"
```

Comment: You're missing a `try` for this `except`.

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place; you are also iterating over the same file twice, which means that your `row` will always start at the second line and finally - I am not sure your code actually raises a ValueError, it might raise an IndexError though.

Comment: Thanks I accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

Each `except` clause must be associated with a `try` clause. Your code contains one that is not.

Comment: I tried to use a try clause with my second exception but I still keep getting the error.

Comment: Then the `except` clause wasn't associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's working now all the syntax errors are gone. Here is what I have now:

```
#!usr/bin/python

from subprocess import *
import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, solution_id, input_file = argv

#creating time stamp and returning as a string to add to solution id log name
def timeIzNow():  
    full = time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return full

#set up logging to file
LOG_FILENAME = solution_id  + timeIzNow() 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s %(process)d',
                    datefmt='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 
                    filename=LOG_FILENAME,
              filemode='w')   
# defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# setting a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# telling the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# adding the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

#set up configuration Parser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/objectItems.cfg')
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/action.cfg')

#get objects
objects = config.get('Objects', 'objects')

#get actions
actions = config.get('Actions', 'actions')

#if no object is found, run error
assert(sys.argv[1] != None), "object does not exist"

#logging debug 
#logging.debug('object does not exist')

#Get inputs and check value and path to file


try:
    f = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb")) 
except:
    logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')   
else:
    try:  
        for row in f:            
            if solution_id != row[2]:
                print "Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again"
    except ValueError: 
                logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
    else:
        print row     







finally: 
     print "all error checks done!"

# let's do add update delete. that way we don't have to do a conversion in the script from modify to update
# uSE THE CODE THAT i'M USING TO VALIDATE
```